# how to create collapsible network tree view

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, mysql

first of all thanks for reading my question,

I believe image speaks better than words,[image] I created this using Office SmartArt tools.

so the above image show a 3 layer of a user, and my questions is how can I apply this to web using mysql, php, js/jquery/json, html and CSS.

and what I need is those node in **RED** color and **GREEN** color to be collapsible. which is **red** open **green** and each **green** open **violet**

I only have the idea for now, so any suggestion would be appreciate.

thanks

Comment: This question is too general, please try to solve the problem and then ask specific questions about the parts you are struggling with